# SSIS Expression to Isolate a String

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am building an SSIS package that will populate data from an Excel Spreadsheet into our Database for Reporting.

The customer did not provide an individual column for the City  and Unfortunately, the customer cannot update their export file to add the city, so I am trying to build a city column using the Branch Names.

I need an SSIS Expression (or several) to use in a Derived Column Transformation to pull the Name of the Cities out of the Branch Name. The issue I have is that the Spacing and placement of the names varies. I have tried to use Token, Sub string and Right and Left combined with other expressions and I always seem to cut something off.

Has anyone else run into this and how can I fix it. (I am not familiar with C# to use a Script Component).

Here is a Sample of the Data that I have.

```
Branch Name
JS OMAHA - 09
JS SIOUX FALLS - 48
JS DOWNINGTOWN - 53
JS ST PAUL - 70
JS BLOOMINGTON - 103
JS PITTSBURGH NORTH -149-
JS TINTON FALLS - 186
JS BLAINE - 337
JS ROCHESTER MN - 423
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a list of valid cities sitting in a table? If so you can use a lookup transformation.

Lets say your list if cities is in a table called `city`

On the *General* tab pick *No Cache*

On the *Connection* tab tab pick the `city` table

On the *Columns* tab tab match the `Branch Name` column to the city column in your `city` table

In the *Advanced* tab, tick *Modify the SQL statement* and change the end to `where [Branch Name] Like '%' + ? '%'`

Now your lookup will find the closest match and pass it through as an extra column.

The other way is to load it all into a staging table and do an `UPDATE`, also using `LIKE`

Whatever you do, it will help to have a list of valid cities in a table

The other way is to make an assumption about the tokens in the data and use string functions in a derived column transformation to extract it out, but you can get some unexpected results.

I can expand further on these if you wish but I won't waste time if you're never going to return to the question.

Comment: I like the idea of the City Table. It would be something that is simple to do and fairly quick. I tried the Derived Column using Token but with the inconsistent spacing and character sizes it was difficult to get everything. I'll try the Look up Table first. Thank you for the info.

Comment: My Current SQL Statement looks like this. select * from (select * from [dbo].[JOHNSTONE_CityLkUp]) [refTable]
where [refTable].[City] = ? When I modify it, I get big red X in my Lookup Transformation. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What did you modify it to? Try it incrementally to work out what the issue is. First try `[City] LIKE ?`, then try `[City] LIKE '%' + ?` then try `[City] LIKE '%' + ? + '%'`. If you hover over the task you should get a tooltip giving you a clue.

Comment: I tried Multiple variations and got everything from a Syntax error to a connection error. I have now moved to a Fuzzy Lookup Transformation to see if I can make that work. It's a little touchy, trying to balance the character count with the percentage of accuracy to grab everything. It's not working out to well.

Comment: I've taken  another action by creating multiple Transformations and adding an additional Staging table. I am now doing a look-up by Zip Code. Just had to build the Zip Table with the relevant Cities and States. Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst you stated that you are not familiar with script components - they are the correct tool for the job. You will get much greater flexibility by using C# (or VB.Net) code to manipulate your strings. There are a number of good tutorials online to show you how to use a script task, and lots of information about string manipulation in C#.

Comment: If the OP is not familiar with C# then I disagree, scripts are not the way to do it.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Sure they aren't the only way, but definitely the most flexible. What would you suggest they use instead? I think you might be able to use a Derived Column, but it would quickly become unwieldy and complicated.

Comment: There's three other suggestions below. I think it's important that the solution be in something the poster is familiar with... which might be none of the four suggested methods :)

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you, although still think that where possible you should learn to use the best tool for the job. I like (and upvoted) your suggestions though!

Comment: Why thankyou, though I still don't agree it's the best tool. I'm very wary of script tasks because the script editor in my BIDS is now non functional after I installed Visual Studio and I am unable to fix it. So I actually can't edit or create any scripts right now. It's quite disappointing that the tool is that unreliable.